# Delete dynamically created fields with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to create dynamic fields when user wants to add more fields:

```
function addNewField()
{
    var newTextField = document.createElement('input');
    newTextField.type = 'text';
    newTextField.name = 'textInput';

    var newDeleteButton = document.createElement('input');
    newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
    newDeleteButton.value = "Delete";
    newDeleteButton.name = 'deleteTextInput';

    var newLine = document.createElement('br');

    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newTextField);
    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newDeleteButton);
    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newLine);
}
```

It works fine, however, I have to make it so that the Delete button removes the textbox associated with it (along with the delete button itself). How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: try looking at the various solutions already posted -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561277/remove-an-element-from-the-dom-from-reference-to-element-only

Comment: Just as you used "appendChild" you can do "removeChild".

Comment: @ChrisCousins All the fields have the same id/name though, isn't that gonna be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** do it by using `this` and `previousElementSibling` twice (but keep reading):

```
function deleteHandler() {
    var br = this.previousElementSibling;
    var input = br.previousElementSibling;
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(this);
    parent.removeChild(br);
    parent.removeChild(input);
}
```

then

```
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteHandler);
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", addNewField, false);
function addNewField()
{
    var newTextField = document.createElement('input');
    newTextField.type = 'text';
    newTextField.name = 'textInput';

    var newDeleteButton = document.createElement('input');
    newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
    newDeleteButton.value = "Delete";
    newDeleteButton.name = 'deleteTextInput';
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteHandler);

    var newLine = document.createElement('br');

    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newTextField);
    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newDeleteButton);
    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newLine);
}
function deleteHandler() {
    var br = this.previousElementSibling;
    var input = br.previousElementSibling;
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(this);
    parent.removeChild(br);
    parent.removeChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs"></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

**But**, I wouldn't; it's fragile. Instead, I'd get rid of the `br` and put both the text and button in a `div`, then just remove the div:

```
function deleteHandler() {
    var br = this.previousElementSibling;
    var input = br.previousElementSibling;
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(this);
    parent.removeChild(br);
    parent.removeChild(input);
}
```

then

```
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteHandler);
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", addNewField, false);
function addNewField()
{
    // *** Div to contain them
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    
    var newTextField = document.createElement('input');
    newTextField.type = 'text';
    newTextField.name = 'textInput';

    var newDeleteButton = document.createElement('input');
    newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
    newDeleteButton.value = "Delete";
    newDeleteButton.name = 'deleteTextInput';
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteHandler);
    
    // *** Put them in the div
    div.appendChild(newTextField);
    div.appendChild(newDeleteButton);

    // *** Add the div
    document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(div);
}
function deleteHandler() {
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs"></div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a <div> instead of <br>. Also, a question, what is the role of parentElement in here?

Comment: @user10316378 - An element has a property, `parentElement`, which refers to its parent in the DOM tree. So for instance, the delete button's parent element is the `div` (whose parent element is `#inputs`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample syntax for how to remove an element by using that elements id

```
    function remove(id){
                let elem = document.getElementById(id);
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a click event on the newDeleteButton button and use removeChild, like this:

```
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener ('click', function () {
     document.getElementById ('inputs'). removeChild (newTextField);
     document.getElementById ('inputs'). removeChild (newDeleteButton);
     document.getElementById ('inputs'). removeChild (newLine);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after `newDeleteButton.name = 'deleteTextInput';`:

```
newDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newTextField.remove();
    this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better that the input and button set in a "div" but you can add click event on delete button :

```
function addNewField()
{
var newTextField = document.createElement('input');
newTextField.type = 'text';
newTextField.name = 'textInput';

var newDeleteButton = document.createElement('input');
newDeleteButton.type = 'button';
newDeleteButton.value = "Delete";
newDeleteButton.name = 'deleteTextInput';
// ------ add click event to delete ------
newDeleteButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   var input = e.target.previousSibling;
   var br = e.target.nextSibling;
   e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
   input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
   br.parentNode.removeChild(br);
})

var newLine = document.createElement('br');

document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newTextField);
document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newDeleteButton);
document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(newLine);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hadies/f96xqsz0/80/