# How to remove multiple divs with same class from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a container div that contains some text and multiple divs all with class 'test', and I am trying to delete all the divs with class 'test' using pure javascript.

Currently, I have a variable containing all the divs with class 'test' which I have iterated through to remove each one.

```js
var divsToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (var i = 0; i < divsToRemove.length; i++) {
  divsToRemove[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>This text should stay</p>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected all of the divs with class 'test' to be removed, but only some of them have been removed with this code

Comment: `const removeElements = (elms) => elms.forEach(el => el.remove());` and use with `removeElements( document.querySelectorAll(".test") );` REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Comment: The key part is [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a "_live_ HTMLCollection," which means as you remove elements from the DOM, your list changes in length, so iterating over it fails. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a "_static (not live)_ NodeList," which can be safetly iterated over without the length of the list changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're removing elements, the index of them changes, so start from the end and work to the front:

```js
var divsToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (var i = divsToRemove.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  divsToRemove[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>This text should stay</p>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Testing 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution won't work in IE11 as it doesn't support ```remove``` method. 

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561277/remove-an-element-from-the-dom-from-reference-to-element-only)

[Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove)

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns ***live HTMLCollection***, you can try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a static (***not live***) *NodeList*.

```js
var divsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    divsToRemove[i].remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <p>This text should stay</p>
   <div class="test"><p>Testing 1</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>Testing 2</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>Testing 3</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>Testing 4</p></div>
</div>
```